# Unexpected Behavior with XML Lateral Flatten In Snowflake (Rows with 1 value being filtered)

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I am working with some XML data in Snowflake where I am trying to access some data in XML subnodes.

The data I am after looks something like this:

```
<Employee>
     <EmploymentStatuses>
        <EmployeeEmploymentStatus>
            <OtherInformation>
            </OtherInformation>            
        </EmployeeEmploymentStatus>
</Employee>
```

For a given employee, they may have multiple 'EmployeeEmploymentStatus'.

To account for this, I created a view like the below:

```
SELECT
  XMLGET(XML_CONTENT,'EMPLOYEE_CODE'):"$"::STRING AS EMPLOYEE_CODE
  , XMLGET(EMPLOYMENT_STATUS.value, 'EffectiveStart'):"$"::DATE AS EffectiveStart
...........
FROM
  XML_FILE
  LATERAL FLATTEN(XML_CONTENT:"$") STATUSES
  LATERAL FLATTEN(STATUS.VALUE:"$") EMPLOYMENT_STATUS
WHERE 
 GET(STATUSES.VALUE, '@') = 'EmploymentStatuses'
AND GET(EMPSTAT.VALUE, '@') = 'EmployeeEmploymentStatus'
```

The problem I am running into is that while this looks perfect in situations where an employee has multiple 'EmploymentStatus', if they only have one it is filtering them off. (i.e. anyone with 2 or more employment statuses shows ALL of their statuses as you would expect, but someone with only 1 employment status does not appear at all)

If I remove the second lateral flatten and just use nested XMLGET in the select portion, I am able to return the value,  but for employees with multiple 'EmploymentStatus' it only returns the first value.

When looking at the output of STATUSES.VALUE, format-wise they appear identical and have all the same tags.

The only thing I can think to do is basically a union of those two tables, or doing something like modifying the 'where statement to be something like this, which would then require coalesce statements on all the fields:

```
GET(EMPLOYMENT_STATUS.value, '@') = 'EmployeeEmploymentStatus' OR GET(STATUSES.value:"$",'@')::STRING = 'EmployeeEmploymentStatus')
```

I tested this method and it seems to work, but it also seems kind of clunky and unintuitive.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a common bug in XML libraries (so it's not just a Snowflake problem), and the [general accept solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512140/snowflake-xml-parsing-not-working-for-nested-structure-when-there-is-only-1-inst/58513319#58513319) is to get the node that you know can be an array, and cast it to an array before doing the  spilt, so that it always works.

like:

```
lateral flatten(to_array(xmlget(xmlget(src2.cdc_xml, 'portfolio'))))
```

or

```
IFF(IS_ARRAY(master_raw), master_raw, TO_ARRAY(master_raw)) as master
```

Comment: Perfect, that seems to have done the trick. I'll keep that in mind in the future.